# Firebase on iOS doesn't return newly added entry

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Code below works, but for some reason it doesn't return new entry. For example I had 3 items in firebase app returns all 3 of them, but when I add forth item it still returns 3 items without new entry I tested same reference on android and it works without a problem and I'm sure that new entry exists.

```
-(void)loadItems:(NSString *)itemsKey{
[[self.itemsReference child:itemsKey] observeSingleEventOfType:(FIRDataEventTypeValue) withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
    NSLog(@"ITEMS: %@", snapshot);
}];
}
```

Comment: This code in itself looks fine, so likely the problem is elsewhere. For example: do you use disk persistence, and do you keep `itemsReference` synced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change this

```
observeSingleEventOfType
```

to

```
observeEventType
```

for observing new values , or you can observe for childAdded

Comment: it works when I'm changing it, but why observeSingleEventOfType doesn't work? Even after I'm closing app and reopening it

Comment: check if you overwrite the data with setValue